# Error message when connecting to MongoDB with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am connecting to my MongoDB with node.js. The server connects to the database, but I get an annoying error message.

This is the error:

> (node:9252) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

here is my code which is located in a separate file that : `server.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shoppinglist'
}
```

I wish to connect to mongodb without having any errors.
I am running version 3.4.18

Comment: Are you using mongoose or mongodb as your connector node module?

Comment: i am using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not an error, it is just a warning and it would not bother the functioning. If you don't want to see this warning, I recommend two methods.

First, by using `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` you can avoid this warning message.

```
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shoppinglist', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Second, most probably you are using mongo version >= 3.1.0 and to avoid this warning you can use 3.0.x releases.

> ```
> "dependencies": {
>   "mongodb": "~3.0.8"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message suggestion should fix the problem, you  just need to add:

```
{ useNewUrlParser: true }
```

to your MongoClient.connect to be like this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shoppinglist', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: I get an error message saying ```MongoClient not defined``` please write down the full code i need to write.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error it's a warning (related to mongo version):

Mongo >= 3.1.0

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shoppinglist", { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: it doesn't work....look at my code again and tell me how i should write it exactly

Comment: Can you share with me the file where you use mongoURI